# How to perform method after completion UILocalNotification cancelLocalNotification: in iOS 8 or 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I need to present `UILocalNotification` after removing the same one by `cancelLocalNotification:`. The problem is removing performs slowly than firing new one and removes just added notification.

How can I determine that `UILocalNotification cancelLocalNotification:` was completed?

Answer (score 2):

You can wait a little bit after calling `UILocalNotification cancelLocalNotification:`
and register again for the new `UILocalNotification`

Something like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:someNotification];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
/* register UILocalNotification again here after delay */
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call notification with specific timer interval or call after first one is over then local notification it self has `repeatInterval` property and value should be `NSCalendarUnit`. And repeat with specific timer.

Otherwise second option is below delegate method always call

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    // I recieved a notification
}
```

When your get notification in the block

you can remove all local notification and create new one with fire date should be

```
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking,

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]

This will return array of scheduled notifications.

You can either check count of array or NSLog array and get details if local notification is cancelled or not.

Comment: Notification was already showed.  scheduledLocalNotifications returns notifications in waiting list. It is not my case.